# Mdadm can't find raid 1 array created in install partitioning

Tags: partitioning, raid

I installed the Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS onto my system with AHCI set for all the hard drives in the system on the motherboard. I have two 2TB WD raid-ready (red) HDDs as my storage units as well as a 320GB HDD for the operating system. I allowed ubuntu to automatically partition the 320 GB drive for the root file as well as swap, and I configured software RAID for both the 2TB drives. The end result was that there was now a RAID volume #0 that would be my array. However, when i run:
    sudo madam --detail /dev/md0
I get that there is "No such file or directory"
Can you help with this problem?

Comment: Does `sudo mdadm --detail --scan` show anything?

Comment: I figured it out yesterday. I believe that there were RAID controllers either on my WD Red HDDs or BIOS raid that took control of the drives before madam could. The reason why i suspect this is because the 2 drives were in raid 1 through dmraid. I could not figure out how to change over from dmraid to madam. What i did is that i plugged in the drives after the ubuntu server installation, formatted them, and then put them in raid 1 form the command line. It seems to work so far.